# What's with all the "close" votes?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

It seems almost every single question asked on Stack Overflow or Stack Exchange immediately gets a few votes to be closed.

Even highly upvoted questions such as [*Is there a benefit of compiling your code as you go along?*](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/245763/13476) have gotten votes to close.

Do we have a few eager-to-close people running around voting "close" on everything?

Comment: Did you mean to post this here or on MSE? If you are talking about an issue that you feel is network-wide, this question really belongs on MSE.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying.  Are we not in MSE?

Comment: No. We are on MSO (Meta Stack **Overflow**), the Meta for Stack Overflow. MSE is Meta Stack **Exchange**, the Meta for the entire network.

Comment: Here's some background on that: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228888/operation-split-all-the-metas-shall-commence-on-april-16-2014

Comment: I would really need some evidence to believe that "almost every single question" gets multiple close votes. I don't think that hyperbole is productive .

Comment: @DavidRobinson Go look at 10 questions, see that they all have close votes, and then come back making snarky responses.

Comment: Downvotes on Meta indicate disagreement. Probably the point David made about hyperbole is what people are objecting to. See the help center article about [what is meta](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta), in particular the voting section. Also consider that down and upvotes **here** don't effect your reputation, at all.

Comment: Close votes don't count, unless you attract 5 of them with your question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about close votes on questions that aren't necessarily on [so]. Oh, the irony!

Comment: @Oded downvotes never affect reputation anywhere because their weight is so small compared to upvote.  It's the insult and also the effect on the quality of subsequent answers that is effected.

Comment: @CaptainCodeman: I just took a look at 10 questions: yours. Only **one** had pending close votes, your most recent. I cast the 5th and last Too Broad vote. One other was already closed. A 3rd is off-topic by todays standards (it is a request for a library recommendation), so it now has a close vote from me. That still left 7 open questions without close votes on them.

Comment: @CaptainCodeman: You rather have we don't maintain standards and just let the whole thing slip? Then you can say goodbye to all the experts that answer your questions; we'd all leave because of the amount of crap that'll flood the place.

Comment: Hmm well it seems somebody is deleting my posts so I'm not going to waste my time replying here anymore.

Comment: @CaptainCodeman: you mean that lovenote you sent me in the comments? It was flagged and deleted, yes.

Comment: In answer to your question, __yes__.

Comment: You completely missed what I said. Votes on a child-meta don't have reputation associated with them. And that downvotes carry a small penalty relative to upvotes (on main sites) is part of the design. In regards to the "quality of subsequent answers" - show me the numbers - this sounds more like hyperbole again, if you have anything to back it up with, great - why not share that? As for the "insult" part - the votes are directed at the *post* and not *you*, personally - frankly, when interacting with others on the Internet, downvotes are tame.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oh you read it.. why are you still here then?  I thought you said you would leave if everything wasn't flowery for you?

Comment: @Captain: your inability to comprehend what other people at telling you is astounding. If you want to get anywhere in the SE network, I suggest you work on that a bit. And your temper, if that is at all possible.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Scoring imaginary points in this videogame has little effect on my life so I don't really have any aspirations to "get anywhere" on this network.  I think maybe that's what the problem is, we get people like you who have become territorial after spending too much time here.

Comment: @Captain: yet here you are, arguing with strangers on the internet to the point of losing your cool, spewing insults left, right and centre. You totally had me fooled there for a second.

Comment: @CaptainCodeman If you observe revenge downvotes, these are usually reversed automatically (just wait about 24hrs). I you feel this wasn't done properly, you may flag one of these questions for moderator attetnion explain the situation and ask for help.

Comment: By the way, there's some clown going around punching random people on the street outside my house. That in itself proves that my "neighborhood" consists of vicious psychopaths.

Comment: @CaptainCodeman: You have had a total of 3 downvotes, on two questions, so *every single question you've ever asked* is, I'm afraid, more hyperbole. Two votes went to the question I voted to close; most likely that's people reviewing your post in the close vote queue. There *may* be some Meta Effect in play here; you drew attention to your account, in a rather.. forceful and loud manner, and that can draw a backlash, but with just 3 downvotes, it is rather mild.

Answer (score 6):

Consider the sheer amount of different people and personalities that participate on the different sites.

You **can't** please everybody. What's high quality for one person is low quality for another.

What makes one question upvote worthy as far as one person is concerned, makes it downvote or even close worthy as far as another person is concerned.

That's before we even get to trolls and people who generally like to cause mischief. Factor them in and yeah, the random close voters strike again!

### What to do?

Accept that it happens, that it doesn't really matter all that much and **move on**.

### Why doesn't it matter?

First off - closed is not deleted. The question is still there. Still visible.

Secondly, it can be **reopened**. By just 5 people (which happens to be the minimum number of required closers) - and chances are that if the question is good/popular, it will get reopened way faster than it got closed.

As for close votes - they don't remain around forever. They *age* away. So after a while, if the question didn't get closed, they will fade from it, no harm done.

Comment: Well, the problem is that it DOES matter.  That question that has 120 upvotes, has 2 close votes.  If the threshold is 3, that means we only needed one more troll and that question could have been closed before it even got any answers.

Comment: @CaptainCodeman - A few points about this. Closed is not deleted. Just means more answers can't be added. And a closed question can be reopened. Additionally, close votes *age*. If the question doesn't end up closed after a while, they disappear. Don't get hung on the close votes.

Comment: @Captain: the threshold is 5 close votes, not 3. Also, don't confuse popularity with a post being on-topic! Older questions that were popular can and will be closed today if they are off-topic by current standards.